# Problems with PyQt5 multimedia

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtmultimedia

I'm trying to learn a little PyQt5 multimedia for a project and I tried the videographicsitem.py example in their github but it won't render any video. Don't know if it's a codec problem (I've tryed with differnt video formats) or anything else. I running Python 3.5, PyQt5(obviously) on a barely fresh Linux Mint install. Thank you all in advance.

The code can be found here:
https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples/multimediawidgets

Comment: I tried the code and I had no problems, you could explain the error better.

Comment: you will need some basic debian packages for qt5. try `sudo apt-get install qtmultimedia5-dev` I don't use linux but I remember that I needed to install some packages related to multimedia backend for linux.

Answer (score 1):

I tried SyedElec solution and it worked fine, thanks a lot. I did the Qt5 installation using the installer provided by Qt and it's probably not as complete as the repositories version.